# Разбиение строки на массив с помощью регулярки (экранирование символов)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вопрос следющего характера:

как разбить строку на подстроки с разделителем допустим ":" (двоеточие) но надо что бы была возможность заекранировать двоеточие - так что бы при разбиении оно не учитывалось

если сделать так

$parts = preg_split('/:/', "a:b:c:d\:h:g");

то на выходе получим массив:
`Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d\
    [4] => h
    [5] => g
)`
а хотелось бы получить:
`Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d:h
    [4] => g
)`

тоесть что бы подстрока "d\:h" не разбивалаль на две (как видите я специально добавил слеш перед двоеточием) надо что бы "\:" не учитывалось как разделитель - что бы была возможность заекранировать разделитель (что бы он воспринимался как обычный символ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function custom_split($str) {
    $parts = preg_split('/(?<![^\\\\]\\\\):/', $str);
    array_walk($parts, function(&$v) { $v = str_replace('\\:', ':', $v); });

    return $parts;
}

var_dump(custom_split('a:b:c:d\\:h:g'));
var_dump(custom_split('a:b:c:d\\\\:h:g'));

> array (size=5)
>   0 => string 'a' (length=1)
>   1 => string 'b' (length=1)
>   2 => string 'c' (length=1)
>   3 => string 'd:h' (length=3)
>   4 => string 'g' (length=1)
> array (size=6)
>   0 => string 'a' (length=1)
>   1 => string 'b' (length=1)
>   2 => string 'c' (length=1)
>   3 => string 'd\\' (length=3)
>   4 => string 'h' (length=1)
>   5 => string 'g' (length=1)
```

Comment: Не учитывается множественное экранирование символов экранирования, например в такой строке:  

    a\\\\:b\\:c:d\:h:g

Comment: если заменить array_walk($parts, function(&$v) { $v = str_replace('\\:', ':', $v); });

на

array_walk($parts, function(&$v) { $v = stripslashes( $v); });
то кажеться все работает как ожидаеться

Answer (score 4):

Собственно способ позволяющий правильно учитывать экранированные символы не зависимо от количества экранирующих символов.
Используется всего одно регулярное выражение и всего один вызов стандартной функции.

```
$text=file_get_contents("php://stdin"); // a\\\\:b\\:c:d\:h:g
$RE="/\\G(.*?(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*):/";
var_dump(preg_split($RE, $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

Результат:

```
array(4) {
  "a\\\\"
  "b\\"
  "c"
  "d\:h"
  "g"
}
```

Живой пример работы кода на [IdeOne](http://ideone.com/5fXsH4).

Comment: Круто!

Прошу какое-нибудь чтиво о

> (?<!\\\\\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\)

Это сравнение подстрок, я правильно понял?

Comment: @bars, это означает что перед `(?:\\\\\\\\)*` не может быть символа экранирования, то есть первый символ группы `(?:\\\\\\\\)*` не может быть где-нибудь в середине строки `\\*\\\\:*`, то есть такое совпадение не удовлетворяет выражению.  
Дословный смысл всего выражения в целом:  
Включить в совпадение все от конца предыдущего совпадения (**\\G**) до первого двоеточия, или двоеточия перед которым четное количество символов экрана (т.е. экраны экранированы).  
Флаг PHP `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` позволяет включать группы из совпадения в результат, чем я и воспользовался.

Comment: Ага, нашел, [Assertions/Утверждения][1] это называется.

  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Comment: Единственное ограничение по выражению- оно не может вернуть пустое значение например из строки  

    a:b::c
Все пустые значения отбрасываются, и исправить это можно используя `preg_match_all` вместо `preg_split`, если необходимо. Выражение даже не изменится- результат в первой группе.

Comment: Не, не так просто: последнее вхождение отбрасывается. Можно использовать `preg_split`, но без `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`, а в результирующем массиве поудалять все элементы с четными ключами (начиная с конца).

Comment: @Bars, верно подмечено, последнее вхождение можно включить в результат так:  

    /\\G(.*?(?:(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*):|\$)/

Answer (score 2):

Если регуляркой, то можно так:

```
<?

$s = 'a:b:c:d\\:h:g:win\\\\:style\\\\filepath'; // 39 символов
// на самом деле в переменной $s сейчас хранится строка
// a:b:c:d\:h:g:win\\:style\\filepath — 34 символа

$split = ':';
$escape_char = '\\';
// на самом деле $escape_char == '\'

$expression = '@('.preg_quote($escape_char, '@').'*)'.preg_quote($split, '@').'@';

//заменим в строке разделитель ":" на наш условный «boundary» разделитель "\n":
$s = preg_replace_callback($expression, function($match)
    {
    if (strlen($match[1]) % 2 > 0)
        return $match[0];
    else
        return $match[1]."\n";
    },
    $s);

// заменяем экранированные экранирующие символы:
$s = str_replace($escape_char.$escape_char, $escape_char, $s);

$arr = explode("\n", $s);
var_dump($arr);

?>
```

Происходящее внутри анонимной функции, переданной в `preg_replace_callback` объяснить затрудняюсь — там все как-то ровно наоборот работает, нежели я ожидал, но работает.

Советую абсолютно всегда, когда в похапе указываешь строку и в ней есть символ "\" — всегда его экранировать, конечно, кроме случаев, когда этот символ сам явно является экранирующим. Это касается именно кода, а не если строка уже хранится в памяти.

Можно реализовать и не используя регулярки. Кажется мне, что так будет даже быстрее.

Comment: Как сложно :(

Comment: помимо того что както сложновато получилось для данной задачи, Ваш алгоритм не коректно ведет себя в случае с символом новой строки строкой "\n"  
в случае с условным «boundary» разделителем можно обойтись без регулярок

`
$str =  "a:b:c \n new line :d\:h:g";
$str = str_replace('\\:', "[my_secret_symbol]", $str);
$parts = explode(':', $str);
array_walk($parts, function(&$arrayItem){
    $arrayItem = str_replace("[my_secret_symbol]", ':', $arrayItem);
});

print_r($parts);
`

но все равно большое спасибо за Ваш ответ

Comment: Попробуйте этот финт провернуть со строкой "a:b:c\\\\:d".

А "\n" можно было бы заменить и, к примеру, на chr(0)

Comment: Тогда  уж так писать "a:b:c\\\\\\\\:d"

потому что "a:b:c\\\\:d"  и  "a:b:c\:d" одно и тоже 

можно сказать "a:b:c\\\\:d" === "a:b:c\:d"

насчет алгоритма с заменой - согласен что он плохой - собственно поетому и вопрос здесь задал